# After rake db:migrate my 'structure.sql' became different from the git version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Differences are of two kinds:

1. `resource_id character varying NOT NULL`  instead of `resource_id character varying(255) NOT NULL`
2. `created_at timestamp without time zone` instead of `created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL`

Rails 4.2, PostgreSQL Version 9.4.4.1

What should I do in this situation?

Comment: Seems like you are using a different postgresql version than the one which created the `schema.sql` file in the first place

Comment: Check if the version is mentioned in README.md file in your project

Comment: Please read the description for a tag before applying it to your question. The [tag:git] tag is for questions about Git usage and workflows, not programming questions that happen to involve a Git repo. (I've [edited](//stackoverflow.com/help/editing) your question to remove it.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the reason: different PostgreSQL versions.